# Is there a standard C++ equivalent of C#'s Vector3?

Tags: c#, c++, xna

Just wondering if C++ has a standard equivalent of the Vector2/3/4 (structures I think?) in C#?

Edit: For clarification a XNA C# Vector2/3/4 "structures" (I'm not entirely sure what they are) basically hold 2, 3, or 4 float values like a struct in C++ defined as:

```
struct Vector3
{
    float x, y, z;
};
```

I've been basically using just that code in C++, but I was hoping for a standard alternative and was unable to find one.

Comment: When asking questions like this, you need to explain what a Vector2 is - many C++ programmers know little about C#.

Comment: Ah, I'll edit it - sorry I hadn't thought about that but I should have.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Nothing standard that I know of, but here's some code to get you started

http://www.flipcode.com/archives/Faster_Vector_Math_Using_Templates.shtml

If you are using C++/CLI and targeting Windows and .NET, you can use Vector2, etc.

Answer (score 6):

The [Vector3 struct](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.xna.framework.vector3.aspx) in C# is from XNA, not the base class libraries.

The equivelent in C++ would be to use [XMFLOAT3](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.directx_sdk.reference.xmfloat3(VS.85).aspx).

Comment: Oh, hmm, well I only used XNA when I was using C# - my apologies.  Thank you though :)

Comment: @Joe: No problem.  Just letting you know ;)  There is no "standard" Vector3, etc.  (Though WPF includes Vector3D in C#/.NET: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.media.media3d.vector3d.aspx)

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.numerics.vector3?view=netframework-4.8

Answer (score 2):

Though there's no equivalent to Vector3 in *standard* C++, there are several linear algebra libraries that have one. Some that are very small and fast:

- [vmmlib](http://vmmlib.sourceforge.net/) - BSD-licensed, written for OpenGL compatibility
- [Eigen](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Main_Page) - LGPL-licensed, but [it won't make you change your license](http://eigen.tuxfamily.org/index.php?title=Licensing_FAQ)
- [GLM](http://glm.g-truc.net/) - MIT licensed, written to mimic the OpenGL Shading Language

Comment: Thanks for the response!  Eigen looks very attractive, I'll look into it!

Answer (score 0):

A `valarray<complex<T>>` could be used like a `Vector2` in many cases. For `Vector3/4` I know no standard equivalent.

Comment: Thanks, unfortunately I'm in need of a 3/4 version much more than a 2, but I hadn't previously known about valarray, thanks for the knowledge!

Answer (score 0):

I don't believe that there are any "canned" objects in C++ which are equivalent.  The STL `vector` is not the same thing.  That is essentially a dynamic array for storage of any value types whereas the vector that you're referring to is class with added member functionality, typically seen used in XNA graphic applications (in my experience at least).  You are on to something with your recognition of the fact that Vector2/3/4 are data structures.  You could very easily store the values of the W, X, Y, Z components in your own structure, but the added member functions provided with the Vector2/3/4 object would need to be added by you.

Comment: That's the method I've currently been using, but I was hopeful for a standard alternative.  The link provided by Lou Franco looks to be very helpful though!

Answer (score 0):

There are also several C++ 3D graphics libraries similar to XNA, such as [Ogre3D](http://www.ogre3d.org/), [Irrlicht](http://www.irrlicht3d.org/), and others. Might be a bit of an overkill if you only need the Vector3 structure though.